# what is System.getProperty("user.home") output in windows?

Tags: java, linux, windows

I am programming in Java under a Linux environment and the output of

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

is

```
"/home/user/"
```

What would be the result if I were on windows? I do not have access to a machine running Windows.

Comment: It is what it is documented to be. Have you considered looking it up?

Comment: Have you considered ... trying it?

Comment: in linux yes but i do not have windows.. and why people voting  down??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will be the home directory of the current logged in user. c:\Users\${current_user_name}

Comment: In Windows terminology, this is the user's profile directory.  You should note that the name of the directory is not always the same as the username.  (Also, the user's profile directory is usually the wrong thing to be using; document files should be written to the user's documents folder, application files to the user's application data folder, and so on, and these folders won't necessarily be inside the user's profile.)

Comment: In my case returns the DESKTOP folder!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try it.

```
public class Demo
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String demo = System.getProperty("user.home");
        System.out.println(demo);
    }
}
```

then result:

```
C:\Users\bianqi\Desktop\computer>javac Demo.jav

C:\Users\bianqi\Desktop\computer>java Demo
C:\Users\bianqi
```

You can see the current user under that user group。

Comment: i don't  use windows i m just asking if run my jar file program in windows what the directory will be.. any way you gave me 3 results! should it be the last one: C:\Users\user?

Comment: The first line of compiling java
The second line is running java
The third line is the result of the output

Comment: Have not you figured it out?

Comment: should the result be the last line if i print it with System.out....?

Comment: You're right..The last line is the result of System.out.print

Comment: ok thank you i will vote up

Comment: It is a dangerous assumption that it will always use `C:\Users\<username>`, because it can be located on a different drive or have a different name (although Microsoft advises not to do that, you can actually make a custom install config to do that).